# Can someone explain how this sort result is produced?

Tags: python, sorting, key

Lets say that you have the given function:

```
def last(word):
    return word[-1]

print (sorted(['apple','orange','banana','grape','watermelon'], key=last))
```

This will return a list that is sorted by the last index in each string:

```
['banana', 'apple', 'orange', 'grape', 'watermelon']
```

So now can someone explain what happens when we ask for user input to specify an index for each string that we are passing to our function `last`. For example if we change the code to be:

```
def last(word):
    index = int(input('Enter index:'))
    return word[index]

print (sorted(['apple','orange','banana','grape','watermelon'], key=last))
```

Which then if the user inputs the following sequence (1,1,2,2,-1) it results in the list:

```
['grape', 'banana', 'watermelon', 'apple', 'orange']
```

Which doesn't appear to be sorted by indexes 1, 2 or -1.

Can anyone explain what is going on behind the scenes and how Python is handling this case? I understand this a very strange question but I'd like to understand how Python is interpreting these instructions.

Comment: You should add a `print(word)` inside your `last` function, to see what word you're setting the index for. That may clear up some confusion.

Comment: @Blued00d: so what order did you expect the sort to end up as? What characters do you think the indices `(1,1,2,2,-1)` would have produced for `sorted()` to sort by?

Comment: @StefanPochmann I believe OP is referring to `sorted`...

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga Ah, right, `sorted` is higher order. Odd to call a popular builtin *"This Higher Order Function"*. I think they're referring to `last`, but meh, whatever.

Comment: @StefanPochmann I did a double-take as well.

Answer (score 2):

The sort is *exactly right*. You asked for the words to be sorted by indices `(1, 1, 2, 2, -1)`. Lets examine what characters those are:

```
>>> for index, word in zip((1, 1, 2, 2, -1), ['apple', 'orange', 'banana', 'grape', 'watermelon']):
...     print(word[index], word)
...
p apple
r orange
n banana
a grape
n watermelon
```

So the correct sorted order by those letters would be `('a', 'grape'), ('n', 'banana'), ('n', 'watermelon'), ('p', 'apple')` and `('r', 'orange'`) (where `('n', 'banana')` and `('n', 'watermelon')` are kept in input order as they both are sorted on `'n'`). This is exactly result you got.